# TCP Binary protocol implementation

Tags: tcp, ip

I'm writing a simple binary protocol over TCP/IP: It is composed as below

**[DATASIZE - 2 Byte Fixed][DATA]**

With this solution, even I read multiple messages, I can divide each one by its size, but I have one doubt: It is possible to receive only a "portion" of a single message?

Answer (score 2):

The only messages that you can receive over a TCP streaming service are single bytes.  Anything more complex may be received in single bytes or any multiples.  So, yes, you can receive 'only a "portion" of a single message' in a single receive call.

Comment: When an host send a 10 bytes message maybe I can receive it separated ( like the first 3 byte followed by the last 7 byte ) but it is possibile that TCP lost the first 3 byte and receive only the last 7? ( Maybe in strange situation like cable disturbed or wifi connection )

Comment: 'it is possibile that TCP lost the first 3 byte and receive only the last 7?'  No, not in a well-behaved implementation.  The last 7 would not be delivered to the app layer because of the failed delivery of the earlier 3 bytes - the sequence numbers would be out.